# Graphing function input output relationships on the coordinate plane

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus

Inspired by a video that I saw a while ago to try visualizing the input-output process of functions by graphing $a$, the input, and $f(a)$ the output of the function on the x and y-axis correspondingly. Then I thought about the line running through them,$\,\dfrac{f(a)}a\,(x-a)$, when a graphed a set of $a$ values, such as $a=[-10,-9.9,...,10]$ there tends to be a space on the graph where none of the lines cross. Is there a function for the space?

An example that might be easier to work with:

$f(x)=2x-1$

[image]

Side note: It appears that all of the lines are tangent to the empty space at one point, is there anyway to use that to reverse engineer for the function?

UPDATE: I've successfully solved the problem using one of the most work around methods I could think of, given two lines $\,\dfrac{f(a)}a\,(x-a)$ and $\,\dfrac{f(a+h)}(a+h)(x-a+h)$ (sorry I could not to get the fraction to work correctly, and suggestion on how would be appreciated). Both of these will be tangent to the 'empty space', a problem is then, where on the function are they tangent to? This can be approximated by using smaller and smaller h values. I will spare you having to see me try to type it out in MathJax. Now you know the derivative of the function. I don't have a deep enough understanding of Calculus to solve for that. You can find all of my work so far [here](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/fxlxmdkk25).

My new question is now how do I use integration correctly to find the function of the blank space, and is there any way to do what I did using calculus?

Comment: You need to study [Envelopes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Envelope_(mathematics))

Comment: This looks like exactly what I want, could you recommend and specific resources, such as videos or online guide, such as Khan Academy?

Comment: depends on a few things. Have you taken multivariable calculus yet? If not, you need to know the basics at least. I always recommend Paul's Notes for studying calculus online. Once you have taken multivariable Calc, start with the examples on the Wikipedia page to get an idea what envelopes are. I seen to remember the book titled "Mathematical Omnibus" covering the topic for a couple chapters... I'll look through my copy later.

Comment: I sadly have yet to take multivariable calc. I looked at Paul's Notes but it doesn't appear to have anything specific on multivariable calc, only calc 1,2, and 3. I found a digital copy of Mathematical Omnibus, and it does have a relevant chapter. The book as a whole looks really interesting.

Comment: Calc 3 IS Multivariable calculus :) I'm glad you found an online copy of the book. It is definitely a tough book to read... Back as a freshman in high school I tried to work through it, and progress was slow. Even now, a couple years later, it takes me a while to work through a single page. Nevertheless, let me know if you have any questions (or, better yet, edit and update this question or create another!)

Comment: I guess the only thing left that I would want to say, is first off, thank you, secondly, I'm probably not going to try and teach my self multi-calc all by myself through text files. But I will use the advice that you gave me!