# Simplifying $\lim_{h\to 0} f'(\frac{(f(a)-f(a+h))(a^2+ah)}{f(a)(a+h)-f(a+h)a)})=\frac{-f(a)}{a}$

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, multivariable-calculus

I'm working on a personal for fun project that you can look at the broader question of [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2258351/graphing-function-input-output-relationships-on-the-coordinate-plane) if you feel the need for context, but the gist of it is that I've reached a blockade where the only thing left for me to solve is:
 $$\lim_{h\to 0} f'(\frac{(f(a)-f(a+h))(a^2+ah)}{f(a)(a+h)-f(a+h)a)})=\frac{-f(a)}{a}$$
honestly the entire thing is a mess, an easy way to start would probably to move to
$$\lim_{h\to 0}f(\frac{(f(a)-f(a+h))(a^2+ah)}{f(a)(a+h)-f(a+h)a)})=\int_0^x \frac{-f(a)}{a} \,da$$
but from there I would need to simplify all of $\frac{(f(a)-f(a+h))(a^2+ah)}{f(a)(a+h)-f(a+h)a)}$, but any way of doing that is beyond me. If it is impossible to outright simplify it all, any simplification would be appreciated.

Please excuse me for any errors that I make, or stupid questions, I am basically swinging blind at this point and learning as I go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**If** $f'$ is continuous:
$$\lim_{h\to 0}f'\left(\frac{(f(a)-f(a+h))(a^2+ah)}{f(a)(a+h)-f(a+h)a}\right) =
f'\left(\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{(f(a)-f(a+h))(a^2+ah)}{f(a)(a+h) - f(a+h)a}\right) = (\text{L'H})$$
$$
= f'\left(\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{(f(a)-f(a+h))a - f'(a+h)(a^2+ah)}{f(a) - f'(a+h)a}\right) =
f'\left(\frac{-a^2f'(a)}{f(a) - af'(a)}\right).
$$

Comment: It would appear that $f'$ is not continues as what you acquired is not equal to what I started with in my context. Thank you very much though.